# How to trigger a request every time my app is invoked

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am developing a google assistant app using api.ai. I want to trigger a request to Google People API every time the app is invoked to get email address of the user. 
I have added the request in action mapped to Default Welcome intent and stored the email address fetched into app.data. It works fine when I say "Talk to my test app". But when I add a user expression that invokes another action like "Talk to my test app and do something...", welcome intent is not invoked and request is not made.
What should I do implement this.

Comment: Please, in able to get help post the code you tried to make the question more clear.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to implement this is to use account linking. You should implement an oauth2 server, flag as SIGN IN the welcome intent or other intents in api.ai. When you perform the account linking you can grab the user email and then you can use the same email to the following request using the access token API.AI will forward to your fulfillment.